# Interpolate Up Vector Linearally when Up isn't truly Up?

Tags: c#, math, 3d, directx-11, sharpdx

### Overview

I've been looking around for a while and haven't found an answer so hopefully the community here can help me out. I am re-working my look-at camera (written pre 2000) and am having trouble getting rid of an issue where the look-at and up vectors become aligned causing the camera to spin wildly out of control. I originally understood this to be gimbal lock, but now I'm not so sure of that.

From my understanding of gimbal lock, when pitch becomes aligned with roll, pitch becomes roll; and in essence this is what it appears to be, but the problem is that the rate of change shouldn't increase just because the axes become aligned, I should just get a smooth roll. Instead I get a violent roll in which I can't really tell which way the roll is going.

---

### Updating the Camera's Position

When the user moves the mouse I move the camera based on the mouse's `X` and `Y` coordinates:

```
Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(e.X, e.Y);
Vector2 delta = mousePosition - mouseSave;
mouseSave = mousePosition;

ShiftOrbit(delta / moveSpeed);
```

Within the `ShiftOrbit` method, I calculate the new position based on the look-at, right, and up vectors in relationship to the `delta` passed from the mouse event above:

```
Vector3 lookAt = Position - Target;
Vector3 right = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(lookAt, Up));
Vector3 localUp = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(right, lookAt));

Vector3 worldYaw = right * delta.X * lookAt.Length();
Vector3 worldPitch = localUp * delta.Y * lookAt.Length();
Position = Vector3.Normalize(Position + worldYaw + worldPitch) * Position.Length();
```

This works smoothly as it should and moves the camera around its target in any direction of my choosing.

---

### The View Matrix

This is where I experience the problem mentioned in the overview above. My `Up` property was previously set to always be `0, 0, 1` due to my data being in ECR coordinates. However, this is what causes the axis alignment as I move the camera around and the view matrix is updated. I use the `SharpDX` method `Matrix.CreateLookAtRH(Position, Target, Up)` to create my view matrix.

After discovering that the `Up` vector used when creating the view matrix should be updated instead of always being `0, 0, 1`, I encountered another issue. I now caused roll when yaw and pitch were introduced. This shouldn't occur due to a requirement so I immediately began pursing a fix.

Originally I performed a check to see if was coming close to being axis aligned, if I was, then I set the `Up` used to create my view matrix to the local up of the camera, and if I wasn't then I used only the `Z` axis of the local up to ensure that up was either up or down.

```
float dot = Math.Abs(Vector3.Dot(Up, Position) / (Up.Length() * Position.Length()));
if (dot > 0.98)
    Up = localUp;
else
    Up = new Vector3(0, 0, localUp.Z);
```

However, this was a bit jumpy and still didn't seem quite right. After some trial and error, along with some extensive research on the web trying to find potential solutions, I remembered how linear interpolation can transition smoothly from one value to another over a period of time. I then moved to using `Vector3.Lerp` instead:

```
float dot = Math.Abs(Vector3.Dot(Up, Position) / (Up.Length() * Position.Length()));
Up = Vector3.Lerp(new Vector3(0, 0, localUp.Z), localUp, dot);
```

This is very smooth, and only causes any roll when I am very near to being axis aligned which isn't enough to be noticeable by the every day user.

---

### The Problem

My camera also has the ability to attach to a point other than `0, 0, 0`, and in this case, the up vector for the camera is set to the normalized position of the target. This causes the original issue in the overview when using `Vector3.Lerp` as above; so, in the case where my camera is attached to a point other than `0, 0, 0` I do the following instead:

```
Up = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.Normalize(Target), localUp, dot);
```

However, even this doesn't work and I have no idea how to get it to do so. I've been working at this problem for a few days now and have made an extensive effort to fix it, and this is a big improvement so far.

---

What can I do to prevent the violent spinning using `Vector3.Lerp` when the up isn't equivalent to `0, 0, z`?

Comment: `Vector3.Normalize(Position + worldYaw + worldPitch)` – usually the yaw and pitch are *angles* to keep track of, and importantly the pitch is normally **clamped** to its conventional range (+- 90 degrees). This way the perpendicular local up direction can be easily calculated and you won't experience the alignment problem.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Can you perhaps write up a basic example with some explanations? Like I said, I've been at it for days and would prefer to do it properly.

Comment: I assume you intend to implement a "conventional" FPS-type camera? If not it should be noted that the camera can "flip" upside down or "tilt" if its rotation is not constrained in some way.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it is a look at camera and is able to go upside down but cannot tilt, it can move left, right, up, and down. What I have above will accomplish that but you get violent “tilt” when approaching alignment of axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a vertical plane that is rotated around the vertical axis by `yaw (ϕ)`:

[image]

The camera is only allowed to rotate *with* the plane or *in* the plane, its in-plane orientation given by the `pitch (θ)`:

[image]

`ϕ` and `θ` should be stored and incremented with the input delta. With this setup, the camera will never tilt, and the local up direction can always be computed:

[image]

`d` and `u` are the local front and up directions respectively, and are **always** perpendicular (so alignment won't be an issue). The target can of course be taken as the position + `d`.

But wait, there's a catch.

---

Suppose if you move your mouse to the right; `ϕ` increases, and you observe:

- If the camera is upright, the view rotates to the right.
- If the camera is upside-down, the view rotates to the left.

Ideally this should be consistent regardless of the vertical orientation.

The solution is to flip the sign of increments to `ϕ` when the camera is upside down. One way would be to scale the increments by `cos(θ)`, which also smoothly reduces the sensitivity as `θ` approaches 90 / 270 degrees so that there is no sudden change in horizontal rotational direction.